# SQL Server: using case while insert into

Tags: sql-server, switch-statement

I have the following sql:

```
;WITH DatesCTE AS 
(
   SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) AS [workingDays]

   UNION ALL

   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays)
   FROM DatesCTE
   WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays) < '2017-01-01'
)
insert into dbo.tWorkingDays
     (date,
     CASE ((DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1) when TRUE THEN 1,
        ELSE 0
    END
    )
SELECT *
FROM DatesCTE
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)
```

and following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tWorkingDays]
(
    [date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [is_business_day][bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tWorkingDays] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([date] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I try to execute request I see following:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: `CASE when  ((DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END` It should be okay.

Comment: @Loser no it shouldn't, the comma shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   ;WITH DatesCTE AS (
       SELECT CAST('20160101' AS DATE) AS [workingDays]
       UNION ALL

       SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays)
       FROM DatesCTE
       WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays) < '2017-01-01'
    )
    INSERT INTO dbo.tWorkingDays (date, is_business_day)
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN (DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 NOT IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM DatesCTE
    --WHERE (DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 NOT IN (0, 1)
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got the field list (the fields you're inserting into) mixed up with the select list (the values you want to insert). It should look like this:

```
;WITH DatesCTE
 AS (

   SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) AS [workingDays]
   UNION ALL

   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays)
   FROM DatesCTE
   WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, workingdays) < '2017-01-01'

)
insert into dbo.tWorkingDays
     (date, is_business_day)
SELECT workingDays,
     CASE WHEN ((DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
FROM DatesCTE
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, workingDays) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)
```

You probably don't want the WHERE clause and the CASE in the same query, but the quoted code should at least resolve the syntax error.